# Where are the methods from the IEnumerable interface implemented for built in classes of the MSDN?

Tags: c#

I've been searching in the MSDN to try to see a class in which the methods from IEnumerator are implemented. For example, the ArrayList class. Is it possible to visualize the helper class in which the IEnumerator interface is implemented so that the GetEnumerator() from IEnumerable interface is able to return an instance of this class and the foreach functionality becomes available?
I realize that there is no practical use of this. This would be only for "academic" purpouses, to better understand how the developers from the language built it.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,385 and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,2564

Comment: About *everywhere*.  .NET 1.x required a lot of custom collection types due to the lack of generics.  Winforms has a ton of them for example.  Start from GetEnumerator(), you'll see it create an object of the concrete type that implements it.

Comment: Thank you haim770. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is considered to be an integral part of the platform, so you may not necessarily find it where you think it should be. (It is also obsolete, and you should prefer a generic collection such as `List<T>`.) For example, in .NET, it is not defined in the collections solution, but rather in `mscorlib`, in [`mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#). The [definition of `GetEnumerator`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#L378-L386) is essentially just a single line:

```
return new ArrayListEnumeratorSimple(this);
```

There is also [an overload which iterates over a sublist](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#L388-L404), which is again essentially a single line:

```
return new ArrayListEnumerator(this, index, count);
```

The [definition of `ArrayListEnumerator`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#L2100-L2154) is again rather simple, if you strip out argument validation and such, it is basically just:

```
public bool MoveNext() {
    if (index < endIndex) {
        currentElement = list[++index];
        return true;
    }
    else {
        index = endIndex + 1;
    }

    return false;
}

public Object Current => currentElement;
```

The [definition of `ArrayListEnumeratorSimple`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs#L2541-L2617) is ironically more complex, but still essentially the same.

Note that the .NET source code is quite old, and `ArrayList` is one of the oldest classes in there.

For a more modern perspective, you could look at [CoreFX's implementation in `src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Collections/ArrayList.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Collections/ArrayList.cs), but apart from a more modern coding style, and the use of a sentinel value instead of `null`, it is exactly the same.